# How to redirect to another form view in python code - Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

Through clicking a button the user should create a new order from given values and be *directly redirected to the form view* of the newly created order. Following method is called through the button:

```
@api.one
def method_name(self):
    [...]       
    vals = [...]
    new_order = self.env['sale.order'].create(vals)
    self.write({ 'state': 'review', })
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'sale.view_order_form',
        'res_model': 'sale.order',
        'res_id': new_order.id,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target' : 'self',
    }
```

Sadly nothing happens and I have no clue, what to try next. I tried to change the target to `new` or `current` or the name but nothing changes. Both without success.

**Edit:** see my comment on Carlos' answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute a method of your model from a button, you must define the button as a `object` type like this in your xml view:

```
<button name="method_name" string="My Button" type="object"/>
```

Then in your `model`, if you want to redirect to another view after doing something, you must return the new action:

```
@api.multi
def method_name(self):
    .......
    return {
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'my.model',
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': the_resource_id,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'
    }
```

Comment: I already had everything in place as you said. Except for __`@api.multi`__. And this did the trick! Thanks for your answer